# MySQL Select from the most times this appears

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is kind of a complicated to explain. Their is a part of my site called "Rising Users". The problem is, I can't actually place any users.

Here's a screenshot of my data in PHPmyAdmin:
http://minus.com/mbdP385PZg

My question i'm trying to get through is how do I make it so I can select from `following` where the most time something occurs. In that screenshot it's ID 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT following
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY following
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want all the data and not just the number that occurs the most, I would expand on Joe's query and write:

```
select * from table where following = (select following from table group by following order by count(*) desc limit 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT following, MAX(follower)
FROM table
GROUP BY following
```